# Convert XML in to Rows and Columns in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, xmltable

Convert XML into Rows and Columns in Oracle:

C12 and c13 has multi-values that's why this query is failing 
c12 and c13 has few values under m1, m2, m3 so on till m42 
I want to get all those values in Oracle rows and columns.

```
        12:53:06 SYS@r17dev11> select xt.* from T24.FBNK_AA_ACCOUNT_DETAILS x ,
13:08:58   2  XMLTABLE('/row' PASSING x.XMLRECORD 
13:08:58   3  COLUMNS
13:08:58   4  "CONTRACT.DATE" DATE  PATH 'c1',
13:08:58   5  "VALUE.DATE" DATE  PATH 'c2',
13:08:58   6  "PAYMENT.START.DATE" DATE PATH 'c5',
13:08:58   7  "MATURITY.DATE" DATE PATH 'c6',
13:08:58   8  "BILL.PAY.DATE"DATE PATH 'c12',
13:08:58   9  "BILL.ID" VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'c13'
13:08:58  10  ) xt where rownum<5;
XMLTABLE('/row' PASSING x.XMLRECORD
*
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence    

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
```

below is the xml code 
c12 and c13  contains multiple values and i need all those values in the table

```
 1* select x.XMLRECORD.getClobVal() from T24.FBNK_AA_ACCOUNT_DETAILS x where rownum<2
16:17:31 SYS@r17dev11> /

X.XMLRECORD.GETCLOBVAL()
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<row id='AA132364NK43'><c1>20130824</c1><c2>20130824</c2><c3>20130828</c3><c5>20
130927</c5><c6>20380831</c6><c7>CUR</c7><c8>20180827</c8><c11>20130828</c11><c12
>20130927</c12><c12 m='2'>20131027</c12><c12 m='3'>20131127</c12><c12 m='4'>2013
1227</c12><c12 m='5'>20140127</c12><c12 m='6'>20140227</c12><c12 m='7'>20140327<
/c12><c12 m='8'>20140427</c12><c12 m='9'>20140527</c12><c12 m='10'>20140627</c12
><c12 m='11'>20140727</c12><c12 m='12'>20140827</c12><c12 m='13'>20140927</c12><
c12 m='14'>20141027</c12><c12 m='15'>20141127</c12><c12 m='16'>20141227</c12><c1
2 m='17'>20150127</c12><c12 m='18'>20150227</c12><c12 m='19'>20150327</c12><c12
m='20'>20150427</c12><c12 m='21'>20150527</c12><c12 m='22'>20150627</c12><c12 m=
'23'>20150727</c12><c12 m='24'>20150827</c12><c12 m='25'>20150927</c12><c12 m='2
6'>20151027</c12><c12 m='27'>20151127</c12><c12 m='28'>20151227</c12><c12 m='29'
>20160127</c12><c12 m='30'>20160227</c12><c12 m='31'>20160327</c12><c12 m='32'>2
0160427</c12><c12 m='33'>20160527</c12><c12 m='34'>20160627</c12><c12 m='35'>201
60727</c12><c12 m='36'>20160827</c12><c12 m='37'>20160927</c12><c12 m='38'>20161
027</c12><c12 m='39'>20161127</c12><c12 m='40'>20161227</c12><c12 m='41'>2017012
7</c12><c12 m='42'>20170227</c12><c13>AABILL13265WLWSR</c13><c13 m='2'>AABILL132
95PD9RK</c13><c13 m='3'>AABILL133263FXPS</c13><c13 m='4'>AABILL133568M6DK</c13><
c13 m='5'>AABILL14022VH2JB</c13><c13 m='6'>AABILL14053G95RF</c13><c13 m='7'>AABI
LL140814YYC3</c13><c13 m='8'>AABILL14112M0MZ4</c13><c13 m='9'>AABILL14142RRH3P</
c13><c13 m='10'>AABILL14173D6GZJ</c13><c13 m='11'>AABILL14203HY9V6</c13><c13 m='
12'>AABILL142341G2BW</c13><c13 m='13'>AABILL142651P9D9</c13><c13 m='14'>AABILL14
295FC8G1</c13><c13 m='15'>AABILL14326LY4DN</c13><c13 m='16'>AABILL14356GTNDX</c1
3><c13 m='17'>AABILL15022FPV3V</c13><c13 m='18'>AABILL1505397QRV</c13><c13 m='19
'>AABILL15081R8PYH</c13><c13 m='20'>AABILL15112NPQ80</c13><c13 m='21'>AABILL1514
2RS60L</c13><c13 m='22'>AABILL1517394B3C</c13><c13 m='23'>AABILL1520399HHS</c13>
<c13 m='24'>AABILL15234G8QQ6</c13><c13 m='25'>AABILL15265G9TT8</c13><c13 m='26'>
AABILL1529522SSF</c13><c13 m='27'>AABILL15326DJW22</c13><c13 m='28'>AABILL15356B
XFX4</c13><c13 m='29'>AABILL16022LVK4B</c13><c13 m='30'>AABILL160535VKDY</c13><c
13 m='31'>AABILL16082999WH</c13><c13 m='32'>AABILL16113HDW4T</c13><c13 m='33'>AA
BILL16143QBV97</c13><c13 m='34'>AABILL16174QWS79</c13><c13 m='35'>AABILL16204Y60
RR</c13><c13 m='36'>AABILL16235V98PJ</c13><c13 m='37'>AABILL16266XSY2W</c13><c13
 m='38'>AABILL16296GGLQG</c13><c13 m='39'>AABILL16327720SX</c13><c13 m='40'>AABI
LL16357PBM9X</c13><c13 m='41'>AABILL17022R86MS</c13><c13 m='42'>AABILL1705305GMP
</c13><c14>AAACT13265080Q418K</c14><c14 m='2'>AAACT132952XTB10G3</c14><c14 m='3'
```

i can get the values like this one by one

```
  1     select xt.* from T24.FBNK_AA_ACCOUNT_DETAILS x ,
  2    XMLTABLE('/row' PASSING x.XMLRECORD
  3    COLUMNS
  4    "CONTRACT.DATE" DATE  PATH 'c1',
  5    "VALUE.DATE" DATE  PATH 'c2',
  6    "PAYMENT.START.DATE" DATE PATH 'c5',
  7    "MATURITY.DATE" DATE PATH 'c6',
  8    "BILL.PAY.DATE"  DATE PATH 'c12[@m=8]',
  9    "BILL.ID"   VARCHAR2(512)  PATH 'c13[@m=8]'
 10*  ) xt where rownum<5
16:13:51 SYS@r17dev11> /

CONTRACT. VALUE.DAT PAYMENT.S MATURITY. BILL.PAY.DATE                  BILL.ID
--------- --------- --------- --------- ------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
24-AUG-13 24-AUG-13 27-SEP-13 31-AUG-38 27-APR-14                      AABILL14112M0MZ4
08-FEB-13 08-FEB-13 13-FEB-13 08-FEB-14
08-FEB-13 08-FEB-13 01-MAR-13 01-AUG-46 01-OCT-13                      AABILL132695KKSX
19-FEB-13 19-FEB-13 01-MAR-13 19-FEB-14 01-OCT-13                      AABILL13269YF6XQ
```

and then for other values i can change the " m " attribute and i can get other values . but this solution is not so practical

```
  1     select xt.* from T24.FBNK_AA_ACCOUNT_DETAILS x ,
  2    XMLTABLE('/row' PASSING x.XMLRECORD
  3    COLUMNS
  4    "CONTRACT.DATE" DATE  PATH 'c1',
  5    "VALUE.DATE" DATE  PATH 'c2',
  6    "PAYMENT.START.DATE" DATE PATH 'c5',
  7    "MATURITY.DATE" DATE PATH 'c6',
  8    "BILL.PAY.DATE"  DATE PATH 'c12[@m=7]',
  9    "BILL.ID"   VARCHAR2(512)  PATH 'c13[@m=7]'
 10*  ) xt where rownum<5
16:13:23 SYS@r17dev11> /

CONTRACT. VALUE.DAT PAYMENT.S MATURITY. BILL.PAY.DATE                  BILL.ID
--------- --------- --------- --------- ------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
24-AUG-13 24-AUG-13 27-SEP-13 31-AUG-38 27-MAR-14                      AABILL140814YYC3
08-FEB-13 08-FEB-13 13-FEB-13 08-FEB-14
08-FEB-13 08-FEB-13 01-MAR-13 01-AUG-46 01-SEP-13                      AABILL13239DK15P
19-FEB-13 19-FEB-13 01-MAR-13 19-FEB-14 01-SEP-13                      AABILL132391SQT3
```

i was checking some more documents where we can get all the values in xml format in one single row . i tried this below code but couldnt finish it as its giving all sort of errors

the document i found --> https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0708nicola/index.html

```
1  select xt.* from T24.FBNK_AA_ACCOUNT_DETAILS x ,
  2  XMLTABLE('/row' PASSING x.XMLRECORD
  3  COLUMNS
  4  "CONTRACT.DATE" DATE  PATH 'c1',
  5  "VALUE.DATE" DATE  PATH 'c2',
  6  "PAYMENT.START.DATE" DATE PATH 'c5',
  7  "MATURITY.DATE" DATE PATH 'c6',
  8  "BILL.PAY.DATE"  '<strong/>XML</strong>' PATH 'c12',
  9  "BILL.ID"   '<strong>XML</strong>'  PATH 'c13'
 10* ) xt where rownum<5;
16:43:50  11  /
"BILL.PAY.DATE"  '<strong/>XML</strong>' PATH 'c12',
                 *
ERROR at line 8:
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

i want all the multiple values from c13 in one row only and it contains more than 20+ multiple values..

Hi Alex ,

my actual requirement is to get all the data from that xml into csv format with each value in separate column but this c12 and c13 making it a lot difficult as these contains attributes upto 42 like m1, m2 , .,., m42 and now when i used ur query it gives me out put in single column but wrapping makes it hard to read in excel shit. output messed up in excel shit . is it possible to get the each values of "m " in different columns or some other technique to get this done? . i thought getting it in xml format will be good . table contains 300k rows .

so will it be better to get the data for c12 and c13 in xml format or varchar format with each " m "value in seperate column .
only condition is , it should be in readable format on excel shit. need your advice on this.  table contains 300k rows

Comment: It might help to include an example of the XML record.

Comment: You said you wanted them in rows and columns; your edit says want them (but now only c13?) in one row, but doesn't explain how. You mention XML but it isn't clear if that is what you want or think you have to have, or what form it should take. Please clarify, and show the output you want to achieve for that sample data.

Comment: no i want c12 in different column and c13 also in different column . my apologies   i could not explain the issues properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a loop in your XPath expression to transform your XML into a separate dummy row for each bill date/ID pair, something like:

```
select xt.*
from t24.fbnk_aa_account_details x
cross join xmltable('for $r in /row, $i in (1 to count(row/c12))
  return (
    element {"row"} {
      element {"c1"} {$r/c1},
      element {"c2"} {$r/c2},
      element {"c5"} {$r/c5},
      element {"c6"} {$r/c6},
      element {"c12"} {$r/c12[$i]},
      element {"c13"} {$r/c13[$i]}
    }
  )'
  passing x.xmlrecord 
  columns
    "CONTRACT.DATE" date path 'c1',
    "VALUE.DATE" date path 'c2',
    "PAYMENT.START.DATE" date path 'c5',
    "MATURITY.DATE" date path 'c6',
    "BILL.PAY.DATE" date path 'c12',
    "BILL.ID" varchar2(20) path 'c13'
) xt
```

Demo with a made-up same XML document that throws the same error you see with your original query:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with fbnk_aa_account_details (xmlrecord) as (
  select xmltype('<row>
<c1>2010-01-02</c1>
<c2>2010-02-03</c2>
<c5>2010-03-04</c5>
<c6>2019-12-31</c6>
<c12>2010-04-05</c12>
<c13>m1</c13>
<c12>2010-05-05</c12>
<c13>m2</c13>
<c12>2010-06-05</c12>
<c13>m3</c13>
</row>') from dual
)
-- actual query
select xt.*
from fbnk_aa_account_details x
cross join xmltable('for $r in /row, $i in (1 to count(row/c12))
  return (
    element {"row"} {
      element {"c1"} {$r/c1},
      element {"c2"} {$r/c2},
      element {"c5"} {$r/c5},
      element {"c6"} {$r/c6},
      element {"c12"} {$r/c12[$i]},
      element {"c13"} {$r/c13[$i]}
    }
  )'
  passing x.xmlrecord 
  columns
    "CONTRACT.DATE" date path 'c1',
    "VALUE.DATE" date path 'c2',
    "PAYMENT.START.DATE" date path 'c5',
    "MATURITY.DATE" date path 'c6',
    "BILL.PAY.DATE" date path 'c12',
    "BILL.ID" varchar2(20) path 'c13'
) xt;
```

which gets:

```
CONTRACT. VALUE.DAT PAYMENT.S MATURITY. BILL.PAY. BILL.ID             
--------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------------------
02-JAN-10 03-FEB-10 04-MAR-10 31-DEC-19 05-APR-10 m1                  
02-JAN-10 03-FEB-10 04-MAR-10 31-DEC-19 05-MAY-10 m2                  
02-JAN-10 03-FEB-10 04-MAR-10 31-DEC-19 05-JUN-10 m3
```

I imagine you could also do this with an XLST transformation, but I'm not really familiar with those.

---

With a slightly cut-down version of the sample XML you added to the question, this code gets:

```
CONTRACT. VALUE.DAT PAYMENT.S MATURITY. BILL.PAY. BILL.ID             
--------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------------------
24-AUG-13 24-AUG-13 27-SEP-13 31-AUG-38 27-SEP-13 AABILL13265WLWSR    
24-AUG-13 24-AUG-13 27-SEP-13 31-AUG-38 27-OCT-13 AABILL13295PD9RK    
24-AUG-13 24-AUG-13 27-SEP-13 31-AUG-38 27-NOV-13 AABILL133263FXPS    
24-AUG-13 24-AUG-13 27-SEP-13 31-AUG-38 27-DEC-13 AABILL133568M6DK    
24-AUG-13 24-AUG-13 27-SEP-13 31-AUG-38 27-JAN-14 AABILL14022VH2JB    
24-AUG-13 24-AUG-13 27-SEP-13 31-AUG-38 27-FEB-14 AABILL14053G95RF    
24-AUG-13 24-AUG-13 27-SEP-13 31-AUG-38 27-MAR-14 AABILL140814YYC3    
24-AUG-13 24-AUG-13 27-SEP-13 31-AUG-38 27-APR-14 AABILL14112M0MZ4    
24-AUG-13 24-AUG-13 27-SEP-13 31-AUG-38 27-MAY-14 AABILL14142RRH3P    
24-AUG-13 24-AUG-13 27-SEP-13 31-AUG-38 27-JUN-14 AABILL14173D6GZJ    
24-AUG-13 24-AUG-13 27-SEP-13 31-AUG-38 27-JUL-14 AABILL14203HY9V6    
24-AUG-13 24-AUG-13 27-SEP-13 31-AUG-38 27-AUG-14 AABILL142341G2BW    
24-AUG-13 24-AUG-13 27-SEP-13 31-AUG-38 27-SEP-14 AABILL142651P9D9    
24-AUG-13 24-AUG-13 27-SEP-13 31-AUG-38 27-OCT-14 AABILL14295FC8G1    
24-AUG-13 24-AUG-13 27-SEP-13 31-AUG-38 27-NOV-14 AABILL14326LY4DN    
24-AUG-13 24-AUG-13 27-SEP-13 31-AUG-38 27-DEC-14 AABILL14356GTNDX
```

but that edit also mentioned getting all of those bill values as one XML fragment still, so you could also do:

```
select xt.*
from t24.fbnk_aa_account_details x
cross join xmltable('/row'
  passing x.xmlrecord 
  columns
    "CONTRACT.DATE" date path 'c1',
    "VALUE.DATE" date path 'c2',
    "PAYMENT.START.DATE" date path 'c5',
    "MATURITY.DATE" date path 'c6',
    "BILL.PAY.DATE" xmltype path 'c12',
    "BILL.ID" xmltype path 'c13'
) xt;
```

which generates (with awkward wrapping for display!):

```
CONTRACT. VALUE.DAT PAYMENT.S MATURITY. BILL.PAY.DATE                                                                    BILL.ID                                                                         
--------- --------- --------- --------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
24-AUG-13 24-AUG-13 27-SEP-13 31-AUG-38 <c12>20130927</c12><c12 m="2">20131027</c12><c12 m="3">20131127</c12><c12 m="4"> <c13>AABILL13265WLWSR</c13><c13 m="2">AABILL13295PD9RK</c13><c13 m="3">AABILL133
                                        20131227</c12><c12 m="5">20140127</c12><c12 m="6">20140227</c12><c12 m="7">20140 263FXPS</c13><c13 m="4">AABILL133568M6DK</c13><c13 m="5">AABILL14022VH2JB</c13><
                                        327</c12><c12 m="8">20140427</c12><c12 m="9">20140527</c12><c12 m="10">20140627< c13 m="6">AABILL14053G95RF</c13><c13 m="7">AABILL140814YYC3</c13><c13 m="8">AABI
                                        /c12><c12 m="11">20140727</c12><c12 m="12">20140827</c12><c12 m="13">20140927</c LL14112M0MZ4</c13><c13 m="9">AABILL14142RRH3P</c13><c13 m="10">AABILL14173D6GZJ<
                                        12><c12 m="14">20141027</c12><c12 m="15">20141127</c12><c12 m="16">20141227</c12 /c13><c13 m="11">AABILL14203HY9V6</c13><c13 m="12">AABILL142341G2BW</c13><c13 m=
                                        >                                                                                "13">AABILL142651P9D9</c13><c13 m="14">AABILL14295FC8G1</c13><c13 m="15">AABILL1
                                                                                                                         4326LY4DN</c13><c13 m="16">AABILL14356GTNDX</c13>
```

Other options are to aggregate the values from the previous query; or have a pair of columns per `m` value (assuming you have a sensible upper limit for that), either directly in the XMLTable call or later by pivoting; or manipulating the bill info into one new node per date/ID and returning all of those as XML still... it depends what output you actually need.